# can't set two semi-transparent borders on an element

Tags: html, css, border

I'd like to have semi-transparent borders on top and bottom. I'm defining the colors using rgba(). Now when the alpha is set to 1 (`border: 1px solid rgba(255, 51, 0, 1);`), both borders are displayed correctly, now after changing this value <1 (`border: 1px solid rgba(255, 51, 0, 0.7);`), both borders disappear completely.

```css
.test{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border: 1px solid rgba(255, 51, 0, 0.7);
 border-left-style: none;
 border-right-style: none;
 background-color: rgba(25, 51, 77, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Works for me in Chrome

Comment: Same, i'm seeing top/bottom borders....

Comment: whops, forgot to change the alpha to value less than 1.

Answer (score 1):

When I try to do this, I can still see the semi-transparent borders in Chrome, see what happens if you make them somewhat larger (5px).
Or am I missing your point? Perhaps there is a browser issue?

```css
.test{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border: 5px solid rgba(255, 51, 0, 0.7);
 border-left-style: none;
 border-right-style: none;
 background-color: rgba(25, 51, 77, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: yeah you're right the borders are barely visible with 1px width ,Setting a greater border width or zooming-in in my browser solves the mystery :) ..thanks for your help :)